# Significant difference between individuals in a group

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, variance

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Doli','Ana','Lili','Sara','Antisha','Felipa'], 
   'mes1': [1.22,1.45,1.78,1.95,1.89,1.56],
   'mes2':[2.54,2.45,2.56,2.89,2.77,2.4],
   'mes3':[1.73,1.45,1.23,2.22,5.32,2.4],
   'mes4':[4.22,3.68,2.24,2.76,1.24,4.56]})

>>>
name       mes1    mes2   mes3     mes4
0   Doli    1.22    2.54    1.73    4.22
1   Ana     1.45    2.45    1.45    3.68
2   Lili    1.78    2.56    1.23    2.24
3   Sara    1.95    2.89    2.22    2.76
4   Antisha 1.89    2.77    5.32    1.24
5   Felipa  1.56    2.40    2.40    4.56
```

assuming that all the observations in the table got the same treament, I would like to test if there is significant vaiance between the different patients. My goal here is to show that no significant difference beacause thay have all gotten the same treatment.

I thought to use ANOVA but seems like ANOVA test differnce between  groups and not between different individuals in the group. In addition, I have here more than one "variable"/dimension  - I have few measurments, all taken in the same day , so i'm not sure how ANOVA can handle this. (I have to use all the dimensions together because they relate to each other- they are different wavelengths measurments).

I also thought maybe to just check the variance inside each group (e.g the given table and other tables of people who got different treatments ) but then I still miss the significancy.

**so my end goal here is to be able to say if this group of people who got that treatments are significantly simmilar/different in their measurments.**

Comment: Could you describe what is mes1, mes2 etc. it is the same structure measured over time or different structures measured once? Is it your full data set?

Comment: @Jakub this is a fake dataset, the real one is wavelength measurments with values between 0-1, measured at once

Comment: Ok, but whether this measurements are repeated? Is other measurements just the repeat of the first one or is another kind of measure? You should describe more specific your data.

Comment: @Jakub - this is not repeated. all of the measurments were taken from the same object on the same time

Comment: If these measurements are not comparable, the variance in that case is undefined.